# How to copy previous rows of a dataframe and copy them to the next one?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe A:

```
date_1         date_2       col1     col2     col1
2022-01-01    2022-01-01    product1  23      23
2022-01-01    2022-01-01    product2  25      50
2022-01-01    2022-01-01    product3  50      50
2022-01-02    2022-01-02    product1  60      23
2022-01-02    2022-01-02    product2  25      50
2022-01-02    2022-01-02    product3  50      50
2022-01-03    2022-01-03    product1  60      23
2022-01-03    2022-01-03    product2  25      50
2022-01-03    2022-01-03    product3  50      50
2022-01-04     None          None     None    None
2022-01-05    2022-01-05    product1  70      23
2022-01-05    2022-01-05    product2  80      50
2022-01-05    2022-01-05    product3  70      50
```

Where the date_2 column is null or none, copy the rows last rows before (2022-01-03) .
As result:

```
date_1         date_2       col1     col2     col1
2022-01-01    2022-01-01    product1  23      23
2022-01-01    2022-01-01    product2  25      50
2022-01-01    2022-01-01    product3  50      50
2022-01-02    2022-01-02    product1  60      23
2022-01-02    2022-01-02    product2  25      50
2022-01-02    2022-01-02    product3  50      50
2022-01-03    2022-01-03    product1  60      23
2022-01-03    2022-01-03    product2  25      50
2022-01-03    2022-01-03    product3  50      50
 2022-01-04    2022-01-04    product1  60      23
 2022-01-04    2022-01-04    product2  25      50
 2022-01-04    2022-01-04    product3  50      50
2022-01-05    2022-01-06    product1  70      23
2022-01-05    2022-01-06    product2  80      50
2022-01-05    2022-01-06    product3  70      50
```

have tried to use the function:

```
df_b= df_a.ffill(axis = 0)
```

I have tried to use the function but it only copies one row, not all the previous ones like the example.

Comment: The dates in the two dataframes are completely different. Looking at the first dataframe can we assume that the `None` value in the column `date_2` should be replaced by `2022-01-03`? When looking at `col1` it seems like the `None` row should be removed as the sequence is always product 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,... . Also you have two columns called `col1` which seems to be wrong as well.

Comment: I have corrected the column dates.
When the date_2 column is null, it would drag the rows of the day 2022-01-03 and add 1 to this date and display as in the second dataframe. (2022-01-04)

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand it now. You want that all three rows of `2022-01-03` are copied and inserted as `2022-01-04`?

Answer (score 1):

First, transform those date columns to a datetime format:

```
>>> df["date_1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_1"])
>>> df["date_2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_2"])
```

Now, find the rows where "date_2" is `None` and find the previous date:

```
>>> previous_date_rows  = df.loc[df["date_2"].isnull(), "date_1"] - pd.DateOffset(1)
```

Then, we go to our original dataframe to find the rows that must be copied:

```
>>> copied_rows = df.loc[df["date_1"].isin(previous_date_rows)].copy()
```

Now we move the "date_1" and "date_2" 1 day forward to match the rows that will be filled/replaced:

```
>>> copied_rows["date_1"] += pd.DateOffset(1)
>>> copied_rows["date_2"] = copied_rows["date_1"]
```

Finally, we can concatenate our non-null rows with our copied (and shifted) rows to complete the output:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df[~df["date_2"].isnull()], copied_rows]).sort_values("date_1")
>>> df
       date_1     date_2      col1  col2  col1.1
0  2022-01-01 2022-01-01  product1  23.0    23.0
1  2022-01-01 2022-01-01  product2  25.0    50.0
2  2022-01-01 2022-01-01  product3  50.0    50.0
3  2022-01-02 2022-01-02  product1  60.0    23.0
4  2022-01-02 2022-01-02  product2  25.0    50.0
5  2022-01-02 2022-01-02  product3  50.0    50.0
6  2022-01-03 2022-01-03  product1  60.0    23.0
7  2022-01-03 2022-01-03  product2  25.0    50.0
8  2022-01-03 2022-01-03  product3  50.0    50.0
6  2022-01-04 2022-01-04  product1  60.0    23.0
7  2022-01-04 2022-01-04  product2  25.0    50.0
8  2022-01-04 2022-01-04  product3  50.0    50.0
10 2022-01-05 2022-01-05  product1  70.0    23.0
11 2022-01-05 2022-01-05  product2  80.0    50.0
12 2022-01-05 2022-01-05  product3  70.0    50.0
```